# We need a new Tag [vulkan]

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think we need a new tag `vulkan` for the [new graphics api](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) from the Khronos group additional to the already existing `opengl` tag

Comment: @muru I've edited the question to make my point more clear.

Comment: [`/vulkan`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulkan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @don_cristi, we now have a [/vulkan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulkan) tag.